# How to Implement Malayalam font Meera for pdf generation using mpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

In my function have added the following codes in  mpdf->confing_cp.php

```
CASE "meera":  $unifonts = "meera,meeraI";  break;
```

also Added the following code in mpdf->config_font.php

```
"meera" => array(
        'R' => "Meera.ttf",                     
        ),
```

And in my controller i need the lanscape view also ,so following are the codes in my controller to generte pdf

```
`

function export_pdf() {
            $this->data['admin_page_title'] = 'Script'; 
            $this->data['portrite'] = $this->input->post('formate');    
            this->data['script_pdf']=$this->Script_model->get_selected();
            ini_set('memory_limit','250M');     
            $html = $this->load->view('admin/script/pdf_view', $this->data,true);
            //include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';    
            $this->load->library('pdf');
            $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
            $pdf = new mPDF('ml', 'A4');          
            $pdf->AddFont('meera','','meera.ttf',true);
            $pdf->SetFont('meera','',14);
            if($this->data['portrite']=="landscape") {
            $pdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
             }
          // $pdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
         //  $pdf->setHTMLFooter($footer);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
           $pdf->Output();
            exit;`
         }`
```